# How to have my TextBox transparent in editing mode

Tags: windows, xaml, c#-4.0

I am working on Windows Phone 8.1 app. This is my actual requirement.

[image]

I want to have my TextBox transparent in editing mode, but I am getting the white color text.

[image]

How to get the transparent TextBox? This is my current code:

```
<Textbox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,267,0,0" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" PlaceholderText="search contacts" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top"  
        Foreground="Black"/>
```

Comment: You want a white background or a transparent background? That's not clear to me (so I didn't edit that sentence).

Comment: i want transparent background

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the property `Background` to `Transparent`. Note that doing this might make it unclear for the user that they're editing the `TextBox` as both read and edit mode will now look the same.

```
<Textbox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,267,0,0" 
     TextWrapping="Wrap" PlaceholderText="search contacts" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top"  
     Foreground="Black" Background="Transparent" />
```